# I get error while trying to read text from file in reactjs/tauri

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, tauri

im building crypto wallet in reactjs and then i will make it in tauri but what im tryng to do now is to read mnemonic from text file but i get this error [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEe49.png)

the code is this:

```
    fetch(raw)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text); // console logs output


    });

    

  const [computer] = useState(
    new Computer({
      mnemonic: (text), // i want here to be output but i get that error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems here. The initial problem, and the reason the error occurred, is because the `text` variable is [out of scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) when you are calling it inside the `useState` hook. You will need to set the state value when you have reference to the `text` variable.

The second problem is that you are wanting to set the initial value of the a state in a react component based off an asynchronous query. Since an asynchronous value cannot be available at the initial render, you need to combine the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable) hook and the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to set the value after the initial load.

With such limited code shown, i will try to fill in the gaps and make an example of what i think you are looking for:

```js
function Component() {
  const [computer, setComputer] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(raw).then(r => r.text()).then(text => {
      setComputer(new Computer({ mnemonic: text }))
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    // whatever you render 
  )
}
```

This way, at render your component will have a default value of `""` and then when the async `fetch` call has finished it will update the value. If you pass an empty array as the second parameter to the `useEffect` hook, it will only be called on the initial render.

Comment: like this? https://imgur.com/a/Vdon3mv

Comment: no you cant call the `useEffect` hook from inside the `useState` hook. you will need to bring it outside and set an initial value for computer

Comment: by the way, I need to get data from text.txt and use it on mnemonic: (here)
also, I forgot to mention that I have "import raw from './text.txt';" this is on top

Comment: you cant import a `txt` file like that. you will need to fetch it we have done above. so instead of `fetch(raw)` it would be `fetch("/text.txt")`

Comment: and what should i put here       fetch(HERE).then(r => r.text()).then(text => {

Comment: you would put the relative path to the file, so based on what you have said it should be `"/text.txt"`

Comment: and doesn't work...

Comment: not much i can do with "it doesnt work" or the amount of information you have shown.

Comment: ```
function App() {



  fetch("/retext.txt")
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(text => {
      console.log(text);


    });

    

  const [computer, setComputer] = useState(

    useState(() => {
      fetch("/retext.txt").then(r => r.text()).then(text => {
      setComputer(new Computer({ 
      mnemonic: text,
      chain: "LTC",
      network: "mainnet",
      url: "//",
      // to run locally, change network and url:
      // network: "regtest",
      // url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000",
    }))
  })
}, [])
)
```

Comment: this is code, there is no errors but it doesn't read it because its show nothing

Comment: You are calling `useState` inside of `useState` where you then try and fetch. of course that doesnt work. there are many issues in the code you posted and it looks nothing like what i showed in the answer.